# Translation of a solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $f$ is locally Lipschitz and $x$ and $y$ are solutions to the differential equation $x' = f(x)$. If there exist real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $x(a) = y(b)$, then $y(t+b-a) = x(t)$ for each $t$ in the interval where $x$ is defined.

How can I prove the statement? Hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_0 := x(a) = y(b)$.

Since $f$ is locally Lipschitz, $x$ is the unique solution of the Cauchy problem
$$
\begin{cases}
x' = f(x),\\
x(a) = x_0,
\end{cases}
$$
defined on some maximal interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Let $z(t) := x(t - b + a)$, $t\in J := I + (b-a) = \{t + b - a:\ t\in I\}$.
It is easy to verify that $z(b) = x(a) = x_0$, and that $z$ is a solution
to the Cauchy problem
$$
\begin{cases}
z' = f(z),\\
z(b) = x_0.
\end{cases}
$$
Since the solution to this Cauchy problem is unique, we conclude that $y(t) = z(t)$ for every $t\in J$.